# SQL database design for multiple rooms check in and check out times for multiple employees

Tags: mysql, sql, database-design

I'm working on a web app that tracks workers check in and check out times to certain rooms. I have multiple employees, multiple rooms, and check in and check out times for each room.  Everytime a worker enters or leaves a room, they scan a QR code that has an ID variable in a URL for that room; I need to record the room, date/time, the employee name, and if it was in or out.

One way is to make one table like:

> **Room | Employee | Time | InOrOut |**

*The data will be entered into database like:*

```
Mens Room, Joe, 6/29 7:30, In

Womens Room, John, 6/29 7:35, In

Mens Room, Joe, 6/29 8:00, Out

Womens Room, John, 6/29 8:05, Out
```

*And I want to view it like:*

```
Mens Room, Joe, 6/29 7:30, In

Mens Room, Joe, 6/29 8:00, Out

Womens Room, John, 6/29 7:35, In

Womens Room, John, 6/29 8:05, Out
```

I want to view data ordered by check in time, but have the following row be the next check out time for that room.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create two look up table..

> 1. Employee {emp_id (pk), employee information}
> 2. Room {room_id (pk), room information}

And one reference table..

> 1. Room_Employee_log {log_id (pk), room_id (fk-Room), employee_id (fk-Employee), log_time, direction (in/out)}

Comment: This is the direction I was heading.  Im trying to figure out how to view the data in a meaningful way.  The manager wants to be able to see when a room was entered and left, to see how much time was spent, etc.  I was thinking of viewing it how I described in my question, not sure how to query it though.

Comment: `select e.name,r.name,l.time from Room_Employee_log l left join employee e on e.employee_id=l.employee_id left join room r on r.room_id=l.room_id order by l.employee_id,l.time;`

Comment: How would I query it so that the room a 'out' log_time is directly after the room a 'in' log_time when there is a room b 'in' log_in time that is between room a in and out?

Comment: Look at the query please, i have ordered the records by employee_id and log_time, So one employee can't enter in second rooms without exiting the first room!! right? it will automatically sort the data as per your need.

Answer (score 5):

You can use three tables:

**Table 1: Employee**

EmpID ............int ........ Primary Key 
EmpName ......... varchar(50)

**Table 2: Rooms**

RoomNo ........ int ........ Primary Key    
RoomDetails .....  varchar(20)

**Table 3: EmployeeInOut**

Id ........int ..... P.K   
EmpID ..... int ....... F.K   
RoomNo ......int ........ F.K   
InTime ...... DateTime  
OutTime ...... DateTime

Comment: Why in 3rd table EmployeeInOut,InnTime,OutTime made separately? We can   make 2 entries like time, direction (i.e. in/ out). Otherwise all is good.

Comment: I do have the first two tables.  I did want to make my third table like you say, but not sure how to do it.  Because, the employee will scan a QR code when going in, enter PIN, and then scan QR code going out, enter PIN.  How would I enter the OutTime to the row that was already created with the in time when employee scanned in?

Comment: @SomnathMuluk Because while querying you don't need to match In or Out with each time. You just need to pick the appropriate column. I feel keeping it separate is better, anyway your choice also works.

Comment: @ScottK You simply need to update the OutTime column. What is the problem?

Comment: @Code1008 How would I update that row?  When the user scans the code, I will have RoomNo, EmpID, and OutTime, but how will I set the OutTime to the same row as where I set the InTime.

Comment: @ScottK How you are inserting inTime?

Comment: @Code1008 When the user scans the code, they enter their PIN. They have two buttons, Check In or Check Out.  Then I insert the Employee, Room, InTime (if they select Check In).  Same process when they leave the room.  How would I know which row to update?  Also, I have possibilities for issues, such as employee forgetting to logout, logging in mulitple times a day to one room, etc.

Comment: @ScottK First just tell me how you are inserting the record. I hope you are using Insert Query.

Comment: Pick the max(Id) of that Employee from table EmployeeInOut and update the OutTime.

Comment: @Code1008 Yes with insert query, such as: INSERT INTO EmployeeInOut (EmpID, RoomNo, InTime, OutTime) VALUES ..... I see how you are saying to do it now with using Id PK (i.e. SELECT max(Id) FROM EmployeeInOut WHERE empID = $_GET['empID'];